# NDK porting c++ to android runtime fault

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk

i'm new here, i was trying port c++ game server code from windows to android armeabi-v7a but i came across this alert from android ndk, the process should continue to run because it is a server:

`C:/Users/Home/Documents/samps/jni/raknet/SingleProducerConsumer.h:138:3: note: when a volatile object spans multiple type-sized locations, the compiler must choose bet
ween using a single mis-aligned access to preserve the volatility, or using multiple aligned accesses to avoid runtime faults; this code may fail at runtime if the har
dware does not allow this access
   if (writeAheadPointer->next==readPointer ||
   ^`

and in the android shows segmentation fault:

[raksamp on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZeSk.png)

Can this be solved? thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using `volatile` ?  If it's for thread communication then it probably needs to be replaced with `std::atomic` or a full lock.

Comment: It was not I created this part of my project, as I am beginner I do not know in what way I can substitute it, you can see it here:[link](https://github.com/TheIceDragon/SAMP-Android-Server)

Comment: Have looked and there is too much code to make a sensible suggestion.  Perhaps you could raise a ticket and point out that `volatile` is not for thread synchronisation and include this: _"...This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution..."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv  And point out the issues you are having on the ARM architecture as well.